# Duplicates in arraylist not to be printed

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist with bankcustomers. Some customers occur more than once (this happens if they have more than one account).

Now I want to print all the customers, but if then occur more than once I only want to print them once.

Heres is my non working code. As it is  now it prints the whole list. How can I add code to only print duplicates once?

```
public void showCustomers() {
    private ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();         

    for(Customer c: customers) {                    
            System.out.println("First name: " + c.getFirstname());
            System.out.println("Last name: " + c.getLastname());
            System.out.println("Customer number: " + c.getNumber());

            for(Account a : c.getAccounts()) {
                System.out.println("Account number: " + a.getAccountId());
            }                                         
        }
}
```

I prefer not to use HashSet (if it's not neccesary). I'm trying to learn ArrayLists now.

Comment: You want the list of only duplicate `Costomer`'s ??

Comment: If customer number is unique. Use it to check duplicate

Comment: Which duplicate would you like to print?  The first, last, nth ?

Comment: @WundwinBorn Yes customer number is unique. How can the code look like?

Comment: @mrres1 It does not matter if I print the first or the last duplicate, as long as it does not prints several times

Comment: Learn to use the right tool for the job.  When the job description includes "without duplicates", a Set is often the right tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all your elements to a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
for (Customer c: new HashSet<Customer>(customers)) {
```

From the linked Javadoc:

> *A collection that contains no duplicate element*

Comment: Thank you, but I prefer not to use HashSets. I'm trying to learn arrayLists now

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need need to avoid duplicates, think [**Set**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

```
    List<String> lst = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
    for(String s : new HashSet<>(lst)) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `Customer` class already implements `hashCode` and `equals` in the way you expect it you can just use a `Set`.

```
 Set<Customer> uniqueCustomers = new HashSet<Customer>(customers);
```

if you need to keep the original order of the elements in the `List` use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

```
Set<Customer> uniqueOrderedCustomers = new LinkedHashSet<Customer>(customers);
```

if the `Customer` class does not implement `hashCode` and `equals` or you can't implement it, because you don't have the sources, use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and implement a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

Optimally, you'll want to create a parallel array within the `showCustomers()` method.

Have the array contain a relative `boolean` value.

Within the `for(Customer c: customers)` iteration create (nest) a conditional statement (an `if`, `else`).

From within the conditional, acquire the value at the nth index of the parallel array.

If the current value is `false` set it to `true` and print out to the console.

If the current value is `true`, then call the `continue` statement to have the iteration go to the next item (and not print to the console).

The following will print the first `Customer` of the duplicate or multiple entries:

```
public void showCustomers() {
    // Visibility of variables in class methods is irrelevant
    // All variables/values created within a method will only be 
    //  accessible from within it's scope
    /*private*/ ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();         

    // Create a parallel list
    List<Boolean> customers_b = new ArrayList<Boolean>(customers.size());

    // Use this value to hold the index of your current item
    int n = 0;

    for(Customer c: customers) {                    

        if(customers_b.get(n) == false)
        {
            System.out.println("First name: " + c.getFirstname());
            System.out.println("Last name: " + c.getFirstname());
            System.out.println("Customer number: " + c.getNumber());

            for(Account a : c.getAccounts()) {
                System.out.println("Account number: " + a.getAccountId());
            } 

            customers_b.set(n, true);

            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            n++;

            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I will try your solution later tonight. I will let  you know.

Comment: I used the above solution, with a HashSet. Thank you for your time. I'm sure your solutions would have worked fine, as well

Answer (score 0):

convert your list into a **Hashset** and this will do the trick, since hashsets doesn't allow duplicate values to be stored but in case of **HashMap** and if there's a duplicate, it replaces the old value with the new one.